# Gulp-sourcemap, browserify and babelify

Tags: javascript, gulp

I'm writing a react app using gulp to build and babelify to transpile.

I use the following definition of `browserify` task :

```
gulp.task('browserify', function() {
    var entries = glob.sync('./app/**/*.js*');
    var bundler = browserify({entries: entries, debug: true})
        .transform("babelify", {presets: ["es2015", "react"]})
        .bundle()
        .on('error', function(err) {
            console.error(err);
        })
        .pipe(source('bundle.js'))
        .pipe(buffer())
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init({loadMaps: true}))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

I get one `bundle.js` while I expect to see transpiled `js` files in `dist` with the same folder structure as `src` (here `app`).

Am I expecting a right thing ? If yes, how can I make it to work like what I expect.

Answer (score 0):

you should remove

```
.pipe(sourcemaps.init({loadMaps: true}))
.pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))
```

which are useless while you are using debug: true on browserify.
the debug: true option writes directly the sourcemaps on bundle.js with base64 encoding. So on your browser, you get source files separatly.